# Given the phrase "Where NONE of the following are TRUE" and two statements how should a boolean logic be composed?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

### **UPDATED with a better example

Let's have two statements

1. **(value > 15)**
2. **(value > 25)**

And a list of items with the following values

- 10
- 20
- 30

This is what a truth table would give

```
Item  Value  (value > 15)  (value > 25)
----  -----  ------------  ------------
1     10     FALSE         FALSE
2     20     TRUE          FALSE
3     30     TRUE          TRUE
```

### Example 1

```
Where ALL of the following are TRUE
   value > 15
   value > 25
```

This one is easy and we get the following

```
Where (value > 15) AND (value > 25)
```

The result is then a single value of 30

### Example 2

```
Where NONE of the following are TRUE
   value > 15
   value > 25
```

This is where I am not sure of what to generate.

This would be "simple" as it is only a NOT of the whole expression

```
Where NOT ((value > 15) AND (value > 25))
```

However, the result is then two values (10 and 20)

From what someone would think of NONE of the two statements would be something like:

```
Where NOT ((value > 15) OR (value > 25))
```

And the result would be that 10 is returned.

What is the correct meaning of NONE here?

Comment: +1. Your question looks perfectly fine to me. It's actually very nicely written.

Comment: This has to be taken in the context of a table of values. I think the correct assumption would be that no value would be returned.

Comment: Well, according to DeMorgan we have ! (A * B) = !A + !B... however it feel more natural having ! (A + B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent "none of (a, b, etc) is true" by either

```
(NOT a) AND (NOT b) AND (NOT etc)
```

or

```
NOT (a OR b OR etc)
```

Either will work.

In your case, you could say `NOT ((value > 15) OR (value > 25))`.  Only 10 matches.

Comment: So NONE (a,b) is not the same as NOT (a AND b)?

Comment: I guess DeMorgan's laws are not applicable for NONE?

Comment: NONE is not a logical operator.  :)  It basically means "all these are false".  And DeMorgan does cover that case (at least for two conditions); `(NOT a) AND (NOT B)` == `NOT (a OR B)`.

Answer (score 3):

None in this instance means NOT on both of the instances, AND'd together.

```
   Where NOT(value > 15) AND NOT (value > 25)
```

Using Demorgan's Law, we can extract the NOT to mean:

```
   Where NOT ((value > 15) OR (value > 25))
```

Which is the second statement in your Example 2.

Comment: Hmmm, my first example? This is not equivalent... This would return two values (10 and 20)

Comment: @Stécy Sorry, I'll clarify.  I meant your first example towards the end.

Comment: Well, not like the first result of the 2nd example. It produced 10 and 30.

Comment: Since I've updated my question to be more logical would you take a look at it again? TY